# Webform Table missing in Views

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a webform created on our site we want to be able to show the user its submitted values and everything seems to be working but the table, I have downloaded webform views. Please help i'm not very good with css but learning. My thinking is the css in the theme but unsure. We have a drupal 7 site and its seems to show up the way its suppose to.

[image: Fuel Reimbursement][image: Fuel Webform submissions]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So the webform in the 1st photo is

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8/9 you need to install the [Webform View Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views) module.